# php send email with images erroring

Tags: php, html, image, file-upload, html-email

With this script the mail is sent successfully. The problem is that the image sent with the email cannot be opened. I think the problem is that the image upload is not successful. (I use the altervista service for hosting the site, and perhaps the upload folder is not accessible with the altervista service)

HTML SCRIPT:

```html
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="uploaded_file">
    <input type="submit" value="Upload Image" name="submit">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="recaptchaResponse"></form>
```

PHP SCRIPT:

```html
<?php

//Upload the file to the root directory

$image_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name'];
$image_temp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name']; 

print_r($_FILES);

move_uploaded_file($image_temp_name, "/$image_name");

//Send the email

$to = "example@gmail.com";
$subject = "It work";
$body = "<img src='https://example.altervista.org/$image_name'>";
$headers = "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n;";

$mail = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
if(!$mail){
    echo "Error!";
} else {
    echo "Your email was sent successfully.";
}

?>
```

The Output of  "print_r($_FILES)" is:

```html
Array ( [uploaded_file] => Array ( [name] => example.png [type] => image/png [tmp_name] => /membri/.dummy/temp/phpDngqzl [error] => 0 [size] => 5639210 ) )
```

The image in email is like this:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried looking at the image in a web browser. The email client could be blocking the image.

Comment: `"/$image_name"` should perhaps be `"./$image_name"`

Comment: I put "./$image_name", but nothing has changed. Also I added the output of "$_FILES", i hope it can help

Comment: You aren't sending a picture. You're sending a link. Does the link work? It's very unlikely that your web server's document root is your hard disk root directory—you'd be sharing your complete computer contents!